# Python tkinter Tag moving when preforming a function

Tags: python, api, tkinter

Im working on a project using API and tkinter. When running my program the label moves towards the right side as well as the label in the next row below is the program and picture:

```
#Make sure to install the following requests
#pip3 install requests
#pip install emoji

#imports
import requests
import tkinter
import emoji


#defining covid api requests
def covid_stats ():
    
    country = country_input.get().capitalize()
    api_address = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary"
    json_data = requests.get(api_address).json()
    country_data = json_data["Countries"]

    for i in range(len(country_data)):
        if country_data[i]["Country"] == country:
            break
    confirmed_cases = country_data[i]["TotalConfirmed"]
    total_deaths = country_data[i]["TotalDeaths"]

    country_label = tkinter.Label(window, text= country,font=('helvetica', 14, 'bold'))
    country_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

    output_confirmed = tkinter.Label(window, text= "Cases: " + str('{:,}'.format(confirmed_cases)),font=('helvetica', 10))
    output_confirmed.grid(column=0, row=2)
    
    output_deaths = tkinter.Label(window, text= "Deaths: " + str('{:,}'.format(total_deaths)),font=('helvetica', 10))
    output_deaths.grid(column=0, row=3)
    
    

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title ("COVID-19 Stats")
window.geometry("500x500")

country_input = tkinter.Entry(window, width=10)
country_input.grid(column=1, row=0)

bt = tkinter.Button(window, text="\U0001F50D", command=covid_stats)
bt.grid(column=2, row =0)


window.mainloop ()
```

the first picture shows the program before i enter a country and search, and the second if after i do it. insted of being lined up to the left it for some reason leaves a gap.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5It3.png): [image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5It3.png): [image]

Comment: I don't see any difference can you mark where it's going wrong?

Comment: Those two images look identical. Either the difference is very subtle, or you've posted the same picture twice.

Comment: Since you put the `Entry` and `Button` widgets on column 1 and 2, at program starts there is no widgets in column 0, so the `Entry` and `Button` will be put at the left most side of the window.  However, when search result is inserted in column 0, the `Entry` and `Button` will be pushed to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am guessing you want the label 'Canada' to the left of the screen. By default, the widgets are centered inside a grid cell. So to change this default behavior you need to give sticky='w' in your `widget.grid()` as a parameter. Plus don't recreate the label instead use the existing label

here is the corrected code:

```
    #imports
import requests
import tkinter
import emoji


#defining covid api requests
def covid_stats ():

    country = country_input.get().capitalize()
    
    api_address = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary"
    json_data = requests.get(api_address).json()
    country_data = json_data["Countries"]

    for i in range(len(country_data)):
        if country_data[i]["Country"] == country:
            break

    confirmed_cases = country_data[i]["TotalConfirmed"]
    total_deaths = country_data[i]["TotalDeaths"]

    country_label.config(text=country)
    
    output_confirmed.config(text="Cases: " + str('{:,}'.format(confirmed_cases)))
    output_deaths.config(text="Deaths: " + str('{:,}'.format(total_deaths)))

    
    
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title ("COVID-19 Stats")
window.geometry("500x500")

#window.columnconfigure(0, pad=0)
#window.rowconfigure((0,1,2),pad =0 )


country_label = tkinter.Label(window, text= "",font=('helvetica', 14, 'bold'))
country_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='w')

output_confirmed = tkinter.Label(window, text="",font=('helvetica', 10))
output_confirmed.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='w')
    
output_deaths = tkinter.Label(window, text="",font=('helvetica', 10))
output_deaths.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky='w')

country_input = tkinter.Entry(window, width=10)
country_input.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='w')


bt = tkinter.Button(window, text="\U0001F50D", command=covid_stats)
bt.grid(column=2, row =0)

window.mainloop ()
```

Comment: Also if you found this helpful, pls upvote and hit the tick

Comment: Thanks, I also noticed that the magnifying glass emoji is duplicated for some reason is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @p3nguin92 I am on windows and am only getting only one magnifying glass emoji also don't forget hit the tick and upvote if this is helpful

Comment: @p3nguin92 you can also use an image instead of emoji if the problem persist.

Comment: ok thanks, i left a tick but cant upvote because i have below 15 rep